# Updating and reloading entire RecyclerView without adding new cells

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to reload/refresh all the cells in recyclerView, and incase of data change, I need to update the cells instead of adding new cells. I use Firebase for my chat app. In the main chatList, whenever a new message comes, the users name gets duplicated and the new message gets added as a new cell. Instead of doing this, I need the recent message under the user's name to update within the same cell.

I need a code equivalent to swift version of reloadData(), where the entire view gets refreshed and resets.

```
mDatabase.child(jobID).child(UserID).child("Messages").orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {



                                        for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                             String MessageBody = ds.child("MessageBody").getValue(String.class);
                                            mDataList.add(new message_Data(
                                                    jobID,
                                                    UserID,
                                                    UID,
                                                    name,
                                                    MessageBody,
                                                    company



                                            ));





                                        }

                                        mDataAdapter = new message_Adapter(thiscontext, mDataList);
                                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDataAdapter);




                                    }
```

I've tried placing mDataList.clear(); before the for loop, However this only gives me the very last user to whom a message was sent.

Current Chat Screen when a message is received

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use adapter.notifyDataSetChange() or pass position to notify data set changes is the way to update recycler view adapter

Comment: This doesn't work. It just adds a new cell instead of updating the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to a chat app, I recommend you to use the method OnChildListener 
Create this above the OnCreate

```
ChildEventListener ItemsListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) 
    {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists())
        {
            DisplayItems(dataSnapshot);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
};
```

And then call `YourRef.addChildEventListener(ItemsListener);` in the OnCreate

In the displayItem methods you will get everydata snap shot. 
Now simply do what you want with it (add it to tour recycler view and call adapter.notifydatasetchanged() everytime you add a item). 
If someone sends a new message, onchildadded will be call with for only this New message 
If a message is changed, removed, moved it will also be called.

Comment: Sorry for the display I'am writing this from my phone